# how to write on specific column?

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have an excel file with 3 columns. i already store the "B" columns to array list and check it if the value is duplicate or not. now i have problem to write the "Duplicate" value to "C" columns. how to write on specific columns?

[image]

here is my code

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(
            "file name"));

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);     
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);       
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    ArrayList<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1) {                  
                col.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                System.out.print(cell.toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();           
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < 14; a++) {
        if(col.get(a).equals("Order ID")) {
            if(col.get(a).equals(col.get(a+1))) {
                System.out.println("ROW no "+a+"Double Order");
                }
        } else {
            if(col.get(a).equals(col.get(a+1)) || col.get(a).equals(col.get(a-1))) {
                if(col.get(a).trim().length()>0) {
                    System.out.println("ROW no "+a+"Double Order");
                col.add("Double");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("file name");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the API? Did you try getting the corresponding cells and setting their values?

Comment: yes. it should write for one by one row, not full column. i want to write it to one column directly because i have 100+ row

Comment: You can't write to columns but to cells only - and a cell is identified by row and column. Besides that what's the problem with 100+ rows? That shouldn't be slow.

Comment: @thomas i mean,in my excel file have 100+ rows to write the duplicate. i want to write all of row automaticly rather than make it one by one in code

Comment: In the end some piece of code would have to do it one by one. If your's does it doesn't mean you have to write a lot of code (depending on the structure of your data) - it might just be a few lines (see the posted answers for examples). If you'd do it directly via a formula that formula would also operate on a cell-by-cell basis.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate twice to identify and write against duplicate rows separately. You can do it like following:

```
private static void identifyDuplicateOrders() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\home\\test_in.xlsx"));
        final FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\home\\test_out.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            final Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            final Set<String> orderIds = new HashSet<String>();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                final Row row = rowIterator.next();
                final int rowNumber = row.getRowNum();
                // SKIP HEADER
                if (rowNumber == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print("Row " + rowNumber);
                // GET ORDER ID CELL
                final Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
                if (!orderIds.add(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                    // CREATE DOUBLE ORDER CELL
                    row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Duplicate");
                    System.out.println(" " + cell.toString() + " is Duplicate.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" Order is Unique");
                }
            }
            workbook.write(fileOut);
        } finally {
            workbook.close();
            file.close();
            fileOut.close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the word Duplicate in a loop iterating rows, you don't need to hold array of values. To check duplicates you can use Set and check if `add` returns `false`.

e.g.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(args[0]));
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)) {
        Set<String> orders = new HashSet<>(20);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            // skip header if needed
            if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // 1 for OrderId as in example
            Cell orderCell = row.getCell(1);
            if (!orders.add(getValue(orderCell))) {
                Cell infoCell = row.getCell(2);
                if (infoCell == null) {
                    infoCell = row.createCell(2);
                }
                infoCell.setCellValue("Duplicate");
            }
        }

        // write result in new file
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(new File(args[0] + ".result.xlsx")));
    }
}

private static String getValue(Cell orderCell) {
    switch (orderCell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        return Double.toString(orderCell.getNumericCellValue());
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        return orderCell.getStringCellValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```